# avoiding duplicate data in a "customers also bought" table

Tags: sql

I am writing a feature for a store website that will suggest other products that other customers bought with the products in the current customer's shopping cart.

My plan is to have a job that trawls the orders database and updates a many-to-many table tracking how often each pair of products were associated with one another. I thought to have a structure like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+----------------+
| product_a_id | product_b_id | times_together |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+
| 12           | 53           | 118            |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Then I realized that I could not necessarily avoid a duplication of data in the table definition with rows like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+----------------+
| product_a_id | product_b_id | times_together |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+
| 53           | 12           | 118            |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+
```

So to increment an association from a new order, I have to do two queries:

```
UPDATE also_bought SET times_together = times_together + 1 WHERE product_a_id = 12 AND product_b_id = 53;
UPDATE also_bought SET times_together = times_together + 1 WHERE product_a_id = 53 AND product_b_id = 12;
```

Is there a more elegant structure where I could update only with only one query, and avoid rows that necessarily duplicate data in the table?

Comment: What about adding another column that is a primary key and is the sum of the product ids? Can avoid duplicate rows this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `also_bought` table, add a `check` constraint to make sure that `product_a_id < product_b_id`. Make your job add entries in that order. That avoids duplication in the table.

But since you want to be able to look up pairs of product IDs in a simple way, create a view that's a union of `also_bought` with itself, only with the ID columns reversed:

```
create view vw_also_bought as
select a as product_a_id, b as product_b_id, times_together
from (
  select product_a_id as a, product_b_id as b, times_together
  from also_bought

  union all

  select product_b_id as a, product_a_id as b, times_together
  from also_bought
)
```

Now you can look up *any* product ID in a single column and get its corresponding paired product ID and buy counts from the other columns.

Comment: I accepted this answer because the check constraint avoids duplicate data in the table, one of the things I was looking for. Thanks much : )

Answer (score 2):

You could exclude flipped pairs altogether with:

```
    product_a_id <> product_b_id
AND product_a_id < product_b_id
```

You could also do this in one `UPDATE`:

```
SET times_together = times_together + 1 WHERE product_a_id IN (12,53) AND product_b_id IN (12,53);
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way:

```
SET times_together = times_together + 1 WHERE (product_a_id = 12 OR product_a_id = 53) AND (product_b_id = 53 OR product_b_id = 12);
```